# use a function at the result of pandas .loc

Tags: python, pandas

Hy peeps,

I wold like to know if have some possibility to use a function at the result of pandas `.loc` or if exist some better way to do it.

So what I'm trying to do is:

If the value in this series is =!0, then get the values of other rows and use as parameters for one function (in this case, get_working_days_delta), after this put the result in the same series.

```
df.loc[(df["SERIES"] != 0), 'SERIES'] = df.apply(cal.get_working_days_delta(df["DATE_1"],df["DATE_2"]))
```

The output is: `datetime64[ns] is of unsupported type (<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>)`

In this case, the parameters used `(df["DATE_1"] df["DATE_2"])` are recognized as the entire series rather than cell values

I don't wanna use `.apply` or `.at` because this df has over 4 milion rows

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: also, when debugging an assignment like this, first make sure the right hand side actually works before assuming it's the slicing/left hand side that is the issue. and always look at and include in a SO post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors - it is full of really important debugging information, and would for example tell you whether the issue is in the `.apply` or the assignment.

Comment: You need to write `cal.get_working_days_delta` to operate on a Series if you are going to pass it a Series.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a good answer without an example.

But I think the problem is that you need to filter before using apply.

Try

```
df[df["SERIES"] != 0].apply(...)
```